# How can I turn on the browser's cookie functionality?

Tags: ios, web-browsing, mobile-safari

After I changed my Gmail password (on a PC), and try to login (with both the new and old password) on the iPod Touch, the browser shows:

> Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on.

The mail app is working fine with the new password on the iPod. The problem is just the browser.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie settings can be changed in the Preferences app in the Safari topic.